# Can't query labels in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Okey, so I have a wierd problem. I have exported a database from graphene to a new ec2 server on aws, which I've set up myself.

While everything seems to be working fine I can't query on Labels.

```
MATCH (n) RETURN n LIMIT 50
```

returns 50 matches, and displays *(50) Equipment(32) Users(18)

```
MATCH (n:Equipment) RETURN n LIMIT 25
```

returns (no changes, no records)

I can see all the nodes in the graphic display when running the first query as well. And both queries work on the old db on hosted by graphenedb.

Anyone got any ideas on why this is?

Comment: What is the output of `CALL db.labels() YIELD label
return label;`?

Comment: Equipment and User

Comment: Can you copy and past the raw text output of Neo4j Browser?

Comment: `╒═══════════╕
│"label"    │
╞═══════════╡
│"Equipment"│
├───────────┤
│"User"     │
└───────────┘`

Comment: A really very strange issue :) Have you tried `MATCH(n:\`Equipment\`) return n` or maybe `MATCH (n) WHERE n:Equipment RETURN n`?

Comment: Tries both, and neither returns anything.

Comment: Which Neo4j version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 3.3.2 in my current database. The graphenedb one was 3.1.7

Comment: Have you enable the `store upgrade` configuration on your `3.2.2` ? If you do this query, what is the result : `MATCH (n:Equipment) RETURN count(*)` ? What give-you the `db.schema()` ?